# (3.0) Geometry Nodes break Vertex Colors

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245919/134355

I need to use the method shown in the linked post for something of my own, but even when using that exact Node layout and Modifier Setting, it ends up breaking Vertex Colors instead- they turn completely black for the object, cannot be edited, and any attempts to modify them using the Value portion of the Capture Attribute Node have no effect.

I'm not understanding why the result is different.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No information is missing, robot.

Comment: This is a bug I assume. Or it was never intended to work that way so it's hard to say either way, sorry...

Comment: It's strange though, right? Weren't you also using the same version?

Comment: I think it was a beta release. They must have changed or reverted something right before the official release. However if something's broken in 3.0, it's still broken in development because the solution still doesn't work with the latest 3.1 alpha

Comment: Looks like they totally broke something- the Attribute Domain doesn't actually change automatically to reflect the type chosen.

Unless you did have to change it manually in the test version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why it wasn't working, and it's... Kind of dumb? Might be a bug in and of itself:

You have to go to the Group tab on the side of the Geometry Nodes window and manually set the Output's Attribute Domain for the Vertex Color attribute from Float to Face Corner, since it doesn't do it automatically for some reason.

[image]

Comment: If you were able to answer your question, please be so kind and mark this answer as "Accepted Answer". Otherwise, it would keep appearing at the top of the list as unsolved. Thank you!